# Printing specific spots on 2D array to text file? Java

Tags: java, arrays, text, printing, dimensions

I'm almost there, but I'm getting an error to delete a catch for exceptions. Second to the last line of code. Also is there any way to only choose specific spots on the array to print out to the text file? Thanks

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Project_Space

{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
// 2D Array of Passengers and Pilots objects- the Passengers class is in the Person.java file
    Person[][] Members ;

  int num_flights= 6;  //create the "x" bound/size of the array
  int num_passengers= 9;     //create the "y" bound/size of the array

  Members = new Person[num_flights][num_passengers];

  //The Members array at index 0 is the first company
  Members[0][0] = new Person.Flight(1);  //This spot in the array is for the Company number in the first spot. Everything else are place holders for data that doesn't pertain to the company
  Members[0][1] = new Person.Pilots(1,"1877963200","Amadeus","Durrutti","Buckminster Cornwallis","1288211435", 11);  //This spot in the array is for the first team member of company #1
  Members[0][2] = new Person.Pilots(2,"6054350085","Sirius","Sassafrass","Ali Bababa","1776812631", 9);
  Members[0][3] = new Person.Passengers(1,"7065253333","Amy","Hartman","Betty Sue","7708889999", 3, 50000,"0554055405540554");
  Members[0][4] = new Person.Passengers(2,"7545251337","Amanda","Zion","Beatrice Twix","7448656577", 4, 2000,"0554055405541111");
  Members[0][5] = new Person.Passengers(3,"8904448899","Janet","Graves","Neal Wade","4445556666", 5, 3000, "9031029266161432");
  Members[0][6] = new Person.Passengers(4,"8902234567","Kristen","Pickering","Christopher Soto","5685461208", 6, 51500, "0985028135114275");
  Members[0][7] = new Person.Passengers(5,"5000893778","Julianna","Estrada","Jill Hansen","2770779833", 7, 0, "0213595590286251");
  Members[0][8] = new Person.Passengers(6,"2080670437","Regena","Mckenzie","Vicki Cook","6224215759", 8, 250, "8204699533830238");
```

....

```java
  Arrays.deepToString(Members);
 PrintWriter writer;
try
{
  writer = new PrintWriter("flightnames.txt");
for (int i = 0; i<Members.length; i++){
for(int j = 0; j<Members.length; j++){
writer.print(Members[i][j] + ",");
}writer.println();
}} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage()); 
} 
finally{if (writer!=null) 
  writer.close(); 
catch (Exception e) 
{System.out.println("Could not close writer");}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Your `catch` block is _inside_ your `finally` block. Indenting your code properly would make it easier to see that.

Comment: I did that because it kept an error coming up saying "Syntax error on token "catch", for expected". Though you're right it is sloppy down there. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Move your finally block, and it should compile properly. For the future use an IDE and use formatting, it will show you your mistakes faster:)

```
Arrays.deepToString(Members);
PrintWriter writer;
try {
  writer = new PrintWriter("flightnames.txt");
  for (int i = 0; i < Members.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Members.length; j++) {
      writer.print(Members[i][j] + ",");
    }
    writer.println();
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
} catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Could not close writer"+ ex.getMessage());
} finally {
  if (writer != null) {
    try{
      writer.close();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
      System.out.print("Error while closing file: "+ ex.getMessage())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'm sure it got me closer to solving the issue. It now says "The local variable writer may not have been initialized" for both of the lines in the finally block. I've been using Dr. Java because it was offered by my school, though I will probably find something different soon. Thank you so much for your time, and help.

Comment: Whell that is correct, but firstly, you are nicelly checking that in finally block with writer!=null, secondly that is only a warning, and that can be sometimes wrong.
And thirdly, I assume that Members is an 2D array, so rename it to members:) Only class names are written from uppercase, variables and methods are starting from small ones.

Comment: Whell it works fine, and under InteliJ there are no warnings or anything. I replaces members with 2D array, and it nicelly printed it to a file.

Comment: I assumed my naming was off earlier today, it didn't look right. Changed that. Well I realized that it was unnecessary. But either way I've wrote it it still comes up with the same errors. writer may have not been intialized is coming up as an error and it refuses to compile for me. It may just be my set-up.

Comment: Hmm, there must be a problem with my compiler then. I ran your update and got the same errors plus "Unreachable catch block" for the second to the last line. Let me reboot and see if it makes any difference by electrical miracle.

Comment: I would advise using Eclipse, it's a full developer tool, personally I use InteliJ, but it is too heavy, it uses too much memory.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Compiler V20140604-1726, same errors as before. I really appreciate it. I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you actually want is this:

```
...
finally {
    if (writer!=null) {
       try {
          writer.close(); 
       } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Could not close writer");
       }
    }
 }
```

That is, have a dedicated `try`/`catch` around your `writer.close()` call to report that an error was thrown by closing the `writer`.

Also, you need to initialise the writer to `null`. You can't do `if (writer!=null)` (or indeed anything else with `writer`) if the `writer` might never have been assigned.

So change your `writer` declaration to:

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be closer to what I am wanting. Though I've tried a ton of iterations of this code, and it always comes up with some reason to keep it from compiling. "The local variable writer may not have been initialized" Still comes up for this iteration. Thanks for your time bud.

Comment: You need to initialise `PrintWriter writer=null;` in order to be allowed to check `if (writer!=null)` later on. Uninitialised is not the same as `null`.